# Angular.js Access controller from route config

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set up my application so that based on the users device (desktop, phone, tablet) they will be sent to a template corresponding to that device (i.e. someTemplate.phone.html). I have created an app controller and set it on the main site wrapper which sets a device property for the device, which works well for targeting the css for the device, however I can't figure out how I can access the app controller I've created from inside my route config.

```
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html', controller: 'MyCtrl1'});
  $routeProvider.when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html', controller: 'MyCtrl2'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

I'd like to end up with something like:

```
$routeProvider.when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial1' + app.device + '.html', controller: 'MyCtrl1'});
```

Any help would be great, I know in ember I could do this.controllerFor('App'), not sure what I can do in Angular to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reach your app like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
```